# Making inequalities interesting

Tags: inequality, reference-request, book-recommendation

Well, I'm learning olympiad inequalities, and most of the books go like this:

> Memorize holder-cauchy-jensen-muirhead, then just dumbass (i.e bash and homogenize) and use the above theorems.

Needless to say, I feel extremely disintersted in inequalities for this approach.

What are some good books which makes inequality interesting ? (Not involving extremely elementary things like AM-GM, Cauchy, but more advanced like Jensen-Muirhead-Karamata-Schur also) ?

---

*To give clarification what I consider as intersting as of now, the only inequality problem that I found interseting is that the following statement for positive reals*

> $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{a_i}{a_{i-1}+a_{[i+1 \mod n}]} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

*only holds for finitely many $n$. Also one thing that I find interesting is that the bounds which can't be analytically found, but exists.*

Comment: My first thought was [**Geometric Inequalities**](https://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/geometric-inequalities) by Nicholas D. Kazarinoff AND [**An Introduction to Inequalities**](https://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/an-introduction-to-inequalities) by Edwin F. Beckenbach and Richard E. Bellman AND Chapter 7 (pp. 161-204) in [**Problem-Solving Strategies**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387982191) by Arthur Engel, but these are fairly well known and the first two, while even suitable for strong undergraduate math students, might be a bit too soft for someone at the math olympiad level.

Answer (score 1):

Because for $a_i=1$ we have $$\frac{n+1}{2}\leq\frac{1}{2},$$
which is wrong sometimes.

I think, a best way to learn inequalities today it's to read books and papers of Vasile Cirtoaje.

Comment: How this is remotely related to the question ?

Comment: @Alex K Chen See please the inequality, which you posted.

Comment: Oops sorry I am on mobile will correct it later. (BTW, Are you arquady sir ? Thanks for the reference.) Is the books good for preparing for Olympiads (also exposes the interesting side of it ?) ?

Comment: Yes, I am arqady. I think these books they are the best way  for preparing for Olympiads. Also you can read the forum "inequalities" in AoPS.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that you've already been exposed to it, but the great classical reference is *[Inequalities](https://books.google.pt/books/about/Inequalities.html?id=t1RCSP8YKt8C&redir_esc=y)*, by Hardy, Littlewood, and Pólya.

Comment: Now, this book is very very outdated.